# How can I set the Angular base path programmatically prior to initialization?

Tags: angular, cdn

### Background / Goal

- I have an app with multiple environments, each stored in a subfolder of a CDN.

  - e.g. `cdn.com/dev`, `cdn.com/test`
- My goal is to load the dev site (`cdn.com/dev/index.html`) and have it load the corresponding resources from the `/dev/` path.

⚠️ℹ️ **We are doing a build-once, deploy-many strategy, so I do not have the ability to pass the baseHref as part of a build process or similar**.

### The Problem

So far no matter what I've tried, `cdn.com/dev/index.html` attempts to load scripts from the root (`cdn.com/script.js`) instead of the subfolder (`cdn.com/dev/script.js`)

### What I've Tried

#### ❌ Attempt 1: Set `APP_BASE_HREF` and use it as a provider

I set a window variable in `index.html`:

```html
<script>
    window['base-href'] = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(window['base-href']);
</script>
```

Then I attempt to use that value to pass to `APP_BASE_HREF` as part of the provider, in `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
let baseHref = (window as { [key: string]: any })["base-href"] as string;

if (!baseHref.endsWith("/")) {

  baseHref += "/";

}

// I only updated the providers array below
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComingSoonListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: baseHref
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This did not appear to work.

### ❌ Attempt 2: A slightly less naive attempt

I remove the `base` tag from the index.html page on the off-chance it's overriding things.

In index.html, I call the script to capture the pathname:

```html
<script>
    window['base-href'] = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(window['base-href']);
  </script>
</
```

In `app.module.ts`, I create a factory method that captures the window value, and then use it:

```js
const baseHrefFactory = () => {
  let baseHref = (window as { [key: string]: any })["base-href"] as string;
  if (!baseHref.endsWith("/")) {

    baseHref += "/";

  }
  console.log('TS: using baseHref of:', baseHref);
  return baseHref;
}

// Note I just use the factory method below

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComingSoonListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: baseHrefFactory }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- I can see the window value being set (per console logging)
- It appears other files try to load before we can programmatically trigger the `APP_BASE_HREF` factory, and are attempted to load from the root path rather than the path I'd set. When running locally, it appears to work fine, but likely only because the path is `/` naturally.

### ❌ Attempt 3: Set the `base` href directly in HTML

In `index.html` in the `<head>` tag, after the `base` tag has been created:

```html
  <script>
    var baseHref = window.location.pathname;
    if (!baseHref.endsWith("/")) {
      baseHref += "/";
    }

    console.log("setting a baseHref of:", baseHref);
    document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href = baseHref;
  </script>
```

- ✅ The index.html script I added is running (I see the console log)
- ✅ The appropriate base path is being picked up (`/dev/` – I see it in the console log)
- ✅ The base tag is being set correctly (I can see this by inspecting via the browser dev tools)
- ❌ The URL being requested in the browser does not contain `/dev/`

  - Actual URL: `cdn.com/script.js`
  - Expected URL: `cdn.com/dev/script.js`

### ❓(Not Yet attempted) Do I have to modify this at deploy time?

Do I need my deployment script to physically modify `index.html` to use the correct `href` in the `<base>` tag? That would be surprising, but I suppose it's possible. Seems like this would definitely be *an* answer; just hoping it's not *the* answer.

### Question

How do I, at runtime, modify the base path so that Angular will download resources from the correct URL, including the sub-path from the CDN endpoint? Am I able to do this at runtime, or do I need to set this programmatically in the HTML at deployment time?

Comment: How are you serving index.html? ASP.NET? PHP? Are you willing to serve the barebones index.html with server side rendering?

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu great question. In this case the app is being deployed to static storage; no server side rendering capability. If that means I need to update things as part of deployment, that's fine; it just seemed that I should be able to accomplish my goal without that.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue now, and the following hack worked, by setting <base href="${SOME_ENV_VAR}"> then in my dockerfile I am copying index.html to index.html.template and as part of serving the app I run envsubst to replace the env var with the proper path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine, the only ways to modify the base href is:

- ❌ With the `angular.json file` -- but this would be applied at build time, and so wouldn't work for a build-once, deploy-many scenario
- ❌ With the command line, e.g. `ng build --base-href="./dev"` -- but again, this is applied at build time, and wouldn't apply to all the deployed environments after that one build.
- ❌ With the contents of the `<base>` tag within `index.html` itself. But again, when deployed to multiple places, this won't meet my needs.

So, as far as I am able to tell, the solution in this case for me will be to have the deployment script modify `index.html` to ensure the `base` tag within it aligns with the environment it's being deployed to.

I wrote a tiny PowerShell script that can be used during the deployment process, in case it's convenient for anyone else:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Modifies an HTML file to set the base href with the appropriate CDN endpoint.
.EXAMPLE
    # Can use relative path to file
    .\TransformBaseHref.ps1 -PathToHtmlFile ..\code\webapp\dist\webapp\index.html -CDNPath "EnvironmentName"
.EXAMPLE
    # Can use full path to file
    .\TransformBaseHref.ps1 -PathToHtmlFile C:\path\to\index.html -CDNPath "EnvironmentName"
.EXAMPLE
    # When index.html is in Current directory
    .\TransformBaseHref.ps1 -PathToHtmlFile index.html -CDNPath "EnvironmentName"
#>
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "The path to the html file to be updated.")]
    [string] $PathToHtmlFile, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "The name of the CDN subfolder, e.g. 'develop' for the development environment")]
    [string] $CDNPath
)

((Get-Content $PathToHtmlFile).Replace("<base href=""/"">", "<base href=""/$CDNPath/"">")) | Set-Content $PathToHtmlFile
```

Comment: FYI, I've submitted a feature request to the Angular team here to see if we can find ways to create a better experience: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45174

Still happy to hear if I'm missing something big here and this is possible.

Comment: Accepted my own answer because the angular response at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22758 confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the base href to something relative?

```
ng build --base-href ./
```

This will load the files relative to where your index file is.

Comment: Hi Mathew! As I noted in my original question, I am in a "build once, deploy many" scenario. The build runs on commit to the master branch. Those artifacts then need to be deployed to dev, test, qa, and prod. So there is no way for me to set the base href at build time.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Are you suggesting that setting running `--base-href ./` will then allow for relative base hrefs no matter where it's deployed to, and will take it based on the index.html page?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Does passing `--base-href ./` to the build do more than just set the `base` tag's `href` attribute? I set the base tag's href attribute explicitly to "./" but I am still seeing the issue with resources incorrectly trying to load from the root path..

Comment: I have tried updating the build command and modifying the base tag itself, to no avail. resources such as main.js in index.html are still loading from the root of the CDN.